SELENIUM Website blocking automation when in a virtualized environment
I have a website automation that works on several local machines, but when it is in a virtual environment (cloud or docker) the website blocks access. (the request on the website is different, but there is no way to inspect it calmly)
enter image description here
My code (webdrive):
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
     options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
     options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
     options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
     options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
     options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
     options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    
     browser = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        options=options
     )
    
     browser.execute_script(
        "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

I tried everything related to the subject that I saw here on stack and i need know how to run my program in docker successfully

That screenshot is tiny and unreadable. Please upload a better screenshot.

Have you tried manually trying to navigate to the website from the cloud or docker instance? I'm assuming it's blocking because of something in the cloud or docker setup since the site is not blocked from your local machine.

yes, i navigate to the site manually but receive equal result (blocked)
